# Powerbuilder 21 Single Line Edit field colours when not enabled

Tags: powerbuilder, disabled-control, tab-ordering

I have a Powerbuilder 21 screen with several Single Line Edit fields on it. The colours have been neatly set up so that if you can access a field (the Tab Order is greater than 0), it is coloured white; if you cannot then it is the same colour as the main window, thus still able to display the text while having it inaccessible.

If I do a piece of dynamic coding and Disable a field (set Enabled to False) then the colour changes to a rather nasty greeny-grey text on a rather revolting background. If, on the other hand, I try setting the Tab Order to 0, this is no problem except that the actual "Tab Ordering" is lost and you end up tabbing wildly.

Is there a solution please to a way to "disable" the Single Line Edit field?

Comment: When you say 'tab ordering is lost' what do you mean?  If you set one to zero the subsequent ones get reset somehow?  Have you tried to set them programatically once the initial field is set to zero?

Comment: Normally the ordering goes 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, etc. which enables you to tab across the screen from one field to the next. If I set a value to 0, so it is unselectable, then set it back, so 30 to 0 to 30, the cursor does not keep the proper tabbing order. In a multiple case version, however, the cursor goes all over the place.